# React Native fetch Network request failed on iPhone SE and iPad

Tags: ios, react-native, fetch

I have a **React Native** app using **RN 0.40.0** and I'm using fetch to make network requests to a Rails back end. Every request is https. The app is already available on iTunes and Google Play and **a small, but significant, amount of users is getting a "Network request failed" error when initializing the app**.

After doing some checks on crash reporting tools and going through users feedback, this seems to be happening mostly to users with **iPhone SE** and some **iPad** users. Not happening on Android. Not happening on newer iPhones.

I've read a lot of questions here in SO related to the "Network request failed" error, but nothing has been helpful so far.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are the same users getting the error repeatedly, while others are not getting it at all? This is strange and difficult to troubleshoot, especially since you can't reproduce it yourself. If you can, a network proxy such as wireshark might be helpful. Good luck!

Comment: This is too broad to help. Researching about debugging options is the way to go. Unless you identify where is the exact problem is we can't help you.

Comment: I just updated the question to add some useful insights we found today: this is happening to users with iPhone SE and some iPad users.